# Radio buttons uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, radio-button

EDIT* Answer below fixed the problem if anyone has the same problems.

Small problem with my radio buttons i have three lines each with 3 Radio Buttons, i want the user to be able to check any of the radio buttons on the first two lines but only be able to select one option on each line:

For example

User can only select one option from "keystage1yr1" and can only select one option from "keystage1yr2". This all works fine as they have the same "name" so by defualt the user can only select one for each line.

I have tried:

[Deselect Radio Button if another one is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222042/deselect-radio-button-if-another-one-is-selected)

[How do I deselect a whole group of radio buttons when a user clicks on some other button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454653/how-do-i-deselect-a-whole-group-of-radio-buttons-when-a-user-clicks-on-some-othe)

But to know luck although they may help other people.

```
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1yr1" value="Paper" /> <span>&#163;25</span>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1yr1" value="CD" /> <span>&#163;25 excl VAT</span>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1yr1" value="Paper & CD" /> <span>&#163;40 excl VAT</span>

<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1yr2" value="Paper" /> <span>&#163;25</span>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1yr2" value="CD" /> <span>&#163;25 excl VAT</span>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1yr2" value="Paper & CD" /> <span>&#163;40 excl VAT</span>

<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1save" value="Paper" /> <span>&#163;47.50</span>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1save" value="CD" /> <span>&#163;47.50 excl VAT</span>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="keystage1save" value="Paper & CD" /> <span>&#163;75 excl VAT</span>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried most of the answers that have been previosully posted but none seem to work as they are all for two options mine is for 3 :)

Comment: Again what have you tried?  We are not mind readers here.  Provide reference.

Comment: Just use a javascript function to deselect the radio buttons you want deselcted...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222042/deselect-radio-button-if-another-one-is-selected , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454653/how-do-i-deselect-a-whole-group-of-radio-buttons-when-a-user-clicks-on-some-othe Thanks :)

Comment: @cdeszaq can you help me out as im not really an expert with javascript?

Comment: Use the javascript answers in either of the two questions you linked to as a starting point. This isn't hard javascript _at all_. Try some things on your own, and if you can't get it to work, then post what you tried and we'll help you from there.

Comment: @Matt i have added the jQuery tag to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some Javascript that should help you out:

```
// Simply caching the dom queries for speed
$yearstages = $('input[name="keystage1yr2"],input[name="keystage1yr1"]');
$savestages = $('input[name="keystage1save"]');
// I only attach one handler to some parent element:
$('#radios').on('change', 'input', function() {
    if (this.name == "keystage1save") {
        $yearstages.filter('input:checked').prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        $savestages.filter('input:checked').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

An example of this working: http://jsfiddle.net/CUTnY/